# Create a string that contains \0 in the middle

Tags: c, string

I have:

```
char *var1 = "foo";
char *var2 = "bar";
```

and I want to create this string: "foo\0bar\0"

How can I do that? I tried this but of course it does not work:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s\0%s", var1, var2);
```

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%s", var1, 0, var2);` would do it.

Comment: Whelp, "a string that contains \0 in the middle" is not a string to begin with... strings can only *END* with `\0`, any function that deals with strings in C will stop at the `\0`. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: This looks like a classic example of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242137). What were you actually trying to achieve when you decided it was necessary to redefine C's definition of what constitutes a "string"?

Comment: You cannot have a string with a `'\0'` in the middle. A string is by definition terminated by the first `'\0'`. You certainly can have a character array containing `"foo\0bar\0"` -- but every string function will treat its contents as the string `"foo"`. Don't try to redefine what a "string" is; just deal with the fact that you have a character array whose contents are not a string. You'll probably have to keep track of how many characters are significant, and use `mem*()` functions rather than `str*()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. Putting `\0` (aka NUL) in the middle of any string is legal, but it also means all C string APIs will consider the string as ending early; every C-style string ends with NUL, and there's no way to tell the difference between a new NUL you added and the "real NUL", because it has to assume the first NUL encountered is the end of the string (reading further could read uninitialized memory, or read beyond the end of the array entirely, invoking undefined behavior). So even if you succeed, C APIs that work with strings will never see `bar`. You'd have to keep track of how long the "real" string was, and use non-string APIs to work with it (`sprintf` does return how many characters it printed, so you're not operating completely blind).
2. Trying to put the `\0` in the format string itself means that `sprintf` thinks the format string ends there; from its point of view, `"%s\0%s"` is *exactly* the same as `"%s"`, it literally can't tell them apart.

You can work around problem number 2 by inserting the NUL with a format code that inserts a single `char` (where NUL is not special), e.g.:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%s", var1, '\0', var2);
```

but even when you're done, doing `printf("%s", buffer);` will only show `foo` (because the embedded NUL is where scanning stops). The data is there, and can be accessed, just not with C string APIs:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *var1 = "foo";
    char *var2 = "bar";
    char buffer[10] = "0123456789";
    sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%s", var1, '\0', var2);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i) {
        printf("'%c': %hhd\n", buffer[i], buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LboMwEEX3/oqRI4uQ0ApImxe0P9KwcAwOlhI7GkMWqfLt1OYh0VnY19czc654uwjRdQulxbUtK8htUyrzXn8TonQDN6700guOFxGBqDnCauUejxB@CbgarAfHBL6ASmNo9t9PvX/mOPfPrZQV/iRx4T/jJN18fG53@8PYY@/omHI5tEVAmWWCWRqB50QQnOKg12mYkX5CGoQ@p3IL48xdOVj1rMy0JMxgvVZTaF8jgwZMBEdgdV2etCOM0VQxk@EQ69WfWDUtagchr677Aw)

which outputs:

```
'f': 102
'o': 111
'o': 111
'': 0
'b': 98
'a': 97
'r': 114
'': 0
'8': 56
'9': 57
```

The empty quotes contain a NUL byte if you look at the TIO link, but lo and behold, my browser stops the copy/paste at the NUL byte (yay C string APIs), so I can't actually copy it here.

Comment: With `sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%s", var1, '\0', var2);`, use the return value from `sprintf()` to control the next `for` loop.  `n = sprintf(....); for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yeah, I mentioned the return value is useful at the end of problem #1; I intentionally didn't use it in the example because I wanted to show how the changed code (using `%c`) does in fact print all of it, and how there's really two `NUL`s produced, as well as showing which values got replaced in the initialized array that originally had characters from `0` to `9`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common problem when dealing with binary data.

If you want to manipulate binary data, don't use the string tools of strcat, strcpy, etc., because they use null-termination to determine the length of the string.

Instead use the memcpy library routine that requires you to specify a length. Keep track of every binary string as a pointer and a length.

```
char *var1="foo";
unsigned len1 = 3;
char *var2="bar";
unsigned len2 = 3;

/* write var1 and var2 to buffer with null-separation */
/* assuming buffer is large enough */
char buffer[10];
unsigned len_buffer = 0;

/* write var1 to start of buffer */
memcpy(buffer, var1, len1);
len_buffer = len1;

/* append null */
buffer[len_buffer++] = '\0';

/* append var2 */
memcpy(buffer+len_buffer, var2, len2);
len_buffer += len2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not particulary fast or short, but this should do the job

```
strcpy (buffer, var1);
strcat (buffer+strlen(var1)+1, var2);
```